# how to count all the keys in json array in postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a table in which I have form id and the form fields column

```
=======================
form_id | form_fields
=======================
  1     | [abc,def]
```

Now there is one other table that contains the submitted form's response data like this

```
================================
device_id | form_id | response
================================
  101     |    1    | {abc:true}
================================
  102     |    1    | {def:true}
================================
  103     |    1    | {def:true}
================================
  101     |    2    | {xyz :true}
```

I want to get all the count of array values of `form_fields` of `form_id` `1`  in the first table from the second table. I mean result be like

```
{abc:1,def:2}
```

One way is to make a simple json of all the responses then iterate one by one object of json and check the values. Is there any other efficient and better way to solve this? I am new to `postgres` so please ignore if this is too basic to ask.

Thanks!

Comment: [The COUNT function returns the number of rows that match a specific condition of a query](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-count-function/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure about this `{abc:true}` since i only work with values in columns, not key_value pairs, so please correct me if i'm wrong

but if they are also just values (like a varchar/...) this should work

`select count(*) from your_table where form_id = 1 and response = 'abc'`

`select count(*) from your_table where form_id = 1 and response = 'def'`